# Agenda semanal Rails 5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, front-end, agendamento

Preciso implementar uma agenda simples em Rails para apresentação de horários diários, adaptei o model e o controller para adicionar novos agendamentos com data e hora, porém a dificuldade está em apresentar no lugar da list da seguinte forma: [image: agenda]

Procurei em algumas gems para tentar facilitar mas não obtive sucesso, estou codificando tudo na mão mesmo, qualquer dica ou indicação de tutorial será bem vindo!

Obs: Só estou usando jquery no front e não pretendo criar uma api rest, apenas quero apresentar na view da list dessa forma.

Answer (score 2):

Uma rápida pesquisa encontrei isso:

gem [fullcalendar](https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails), esta gem ainda permite integração com Google Calendar

Railscasts [#313](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars) e [#313 revised](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised)

Comment: Vou verificar!
TKS! :D